# solving xy'=y using a power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I let

$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$

This means that

$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$

From the initial statement we have that $xy'=y$

$x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n =0$

$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n =0$

$\Rightarrow -a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n =0$

$\Rightarrow -a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(na_n- a_n)x^n =0$

This means that

$$a_0=0 ,na_n-a_n=0$$

But this cant be true or whichever $a_n$ would be also zero. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $y=a_1x$ is a solution ($1\cdot a_1=a_1$)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt oh I didn't see this but I'm still confused as in why $a_1 \neq 0$

Comment: @SpaceRat Consider $n=1$ from what you have. Does it force $a_1=0$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt oh you're right and all the other cases force for the coefficients to be zero thank you so much